# Why do certain sprites ,look as if they're further back in the window?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am learning how to make games using unity, i have used free sprite packs from unity's store.
i have selected each individual sprite and changed its z position to 0, but when the game runs it looks completely different to how it looks in the editing window.
please help.
Here is a video I recorded.
https://youtu.be/2hb9m01PQBk

Answer (score 0):

Are your sprites on a prefab, or children of another game object? The Transform of the parent object affects the transform of all children.

Comment: As far as i can tell no. How would i check and fix that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a camera problem. Your camera is set to perspective, it is possible to do parallax backgrounds with a perspective camera and you may have already accomodated for it, but that is the first thing I would check.

You can modify this by going to your Main Camera and selecting Orthographic from the Projection drop-down menu.

Comment: thank you, i have given up on this project for 6 months but you game me a spark to start again